Forcing vscode to rerun lint on a python file
python re-linting a file after save is extremely slow on a slow (remote) file system.
Slow is between 5 seconds and eternity - not sure if this is a bug or a feature.
Questions:

Can re-linting be forced ?
Tried 'Pylint: restart server' and 'Pylance: start profiling'

Is it related to because pylint and pylance don't behave well together ?
For example Pylint extension disables Pylance extension in VS Code


Setup: vscode installed and configured with latest Microsoft python, pylint and pylance.
Python: 3.11.5
Note: this issue joins VSCode and Python: Run lint on demand

For some readon  works !
